# Most efficient way to collect associated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For my table "Stores" I want to show some tabs with related records. There are 4 related tables, products, variant_skus, master_skus and vendor_skus. The relations are as follows:

```
store has_many :products
product has_many :variant_skus
variant_sku belongs_to :master_sku
master_sku has_many :variant_skus, :vendor_skus
vendor_sku belongs_to :master_sku
```

Now I've created a concern that I can include in a controller that collects the records from these tables for me, but whenever I open a store page it takes quite long to load, probably because of all the iterations. Is iterating through the associations to collect the records faster than just taking the IDs and querying the database? Or is there an other more efficient way of collecting the records?

```
when "stores"
  @store.products.each do |product|
    @products.push(product)
  end

  @products.each do |product|
    product.variant_skus.each do |variant_sku|
      @variant_skus.push(variant_sku)
      @master_skus.push(variant_sku.master_sku)
    end
  end
  @variant_skus = @variant_skus.uniq
  @master_skus = @master_skus.uniq

  @master_skus.each do |master_sku|
    @vendor_skus.push(master_sku.vendor_skus)
  end
  @vendor_skus = @vendor_skus.uniq
end
```

Update: it works like:

```
@products = @store.products.includes(variant_skus: {master_sku: :vendor_skus})
@variant_skus = @products.map(&:variant_skus).flatten.uniq
@master_skus = @variant_skus.each.map(&:master_sku).uniq
@vendor_skus = @master_skus.map(&:vendor_skus).flatten.uniq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  when "stores"
    @products = @store.products.includes(variant_skus: {master_sku: :vendor_skus})
    @variant_skus = @products.map(&:variant_skus).uniq
    @master_skus = @variant_skus.map(&:master_sku).uniq
    @vendor_skus = @master_skus.map(&:vendor_skus).flatten.uniq
  end
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `variant_sku' for #<Product:0x007f9b398d0820> on the @variant_skus line. I changed the line to: 
@variant_skus = @products.map(&:variant_skus).uniq 
and then the line did not throw an error anymore. The next line is though:     undefined method `master_sku' for #<VariantSku::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f9b34722c80>

Any ideas?

Comment: @stoerebink is my answer helpful for you? if it is, please accept it as the answer.